# What is the proper way to read from the errors channel in Sarama?

Tags: go, goroutine, sarama

I am using the Sarama library written in Go to read from an error channel when I produce a message. The overall code looks like this which is enclosed within a function:

```
producer.AsyncProducer.Input() <- &sarama.ProducerMessage{Topic: topic, Key: nil, Value: sarama.ByteEncoder(message)}
go func() {
    for err := range saramaProducer.Errors() {
        if producer.callbacks.OnError != nil {
            producer.callbacks.OnError(err)
        }
    }
}()
```

As my understanding of go routines goes, my go routine would keep iterating over the `Errors()` channel until it receives one. Is there a way to make it stop listening for errors once my function is done executing?

Comment: If the api expects you to range over a channel, it should close the channel when it's done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use another channel and a `select` to make the loop return.

```
var quit chan struct{}
go func() {
    for {
        select {
        case err:=<-saramaProducer.Errors():
            //handle errors
        case <-quit:
            return
        }
    }
}
defer func() { quit<-struct{}{} }()
```

The orignal `for ... range` loop does not iterate the channel until it gets one. Instead, it blocks until it gets an error, handle it, and waits for a new error again, until the channel close or the `main` returns.

There is a little problem about the above code, that owhen both `quit` and error channel is ready, the `select` picks one randomly, thus may cause a single error loss. If this is worth handling, just put another `switch` with `default` to get that error and then `return`.

Comment: You shouldn't need to handle this case, the package will close the channel (as it should) when the producer is shutdown.